# Comparing Blob's centroid with the center of the bounding box

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, vb6

I'm trying to compare the blob's centroid with a small window centered in the middle of the blobs' bounding box. The dimensions of this window is 20% of the dimensions of the bounding box.

I implemented this algorithm first, to find the blob centroid

and this is the code:

```
For y = 0 To bmp.ScaleHeight - 1
  For x = 0 To bmp.ScaleWidth - 1
    If bmp.Point(x, y) = vbWhite 
      Then 
        Xs = Xs + x
        Ys = Ys + y
        area = area + 1
    endIF
  Next x
Next y
YCenteroid = Ys / area
XCentroid = Xs / area
```

Then I found the width and the height of the blob using

```
BlobHeight = MaxY - MinY 
BlobWidth = MaxX - MinX
```

I have now the bounding box and the centroid How can I compare where is the centroid inside or outside the small centered box about 20% of the bounding box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the edges of the bounding box:

```
MinX    MaxX
  |      |
  ########-MinY
  #      #
  #      #
  #      #
  ########-MaxY
```

Given `BlobWidth`, we know that the centered box starts at `.4*BlobWidth`, continues for `.2*BlobWidth` (up to `(.4+.2)*BlobWidth = .6*BlobWidth`).

```
MinCenteredX = MinX + 0.4*BlobWidth
MaxCenteredX = MinX + 0.6*BlobWidth
```

Now you just have to check if `XCentroid` is between them, that is:

```
MinCenteredX <= XCentroid And XCentroid <= MaxCenteredX
```

Now do the same again for the Y coordinates and you're done.